# Code printing hello world despite being math

Tags: java, math

I'm trying this on repl.it and it just... prints "hello world" as a default. I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    class Input{
      public static void mian(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first double: ");
        double firstDouble = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("You entered " + firstDouble + " as your first number.");

        System.out.print("Enter you second double: ");
        double secondDouble = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("You entered " + secondDouble + " as you second number.");

        System.out.print("Enter your third double: ");
        double thirdDouble = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("You entered " + thirdDouble + "As your third number.");

        input.close();

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `main` method is called `mian`.

Other than that, if you didn't change the default name of the first file, you should name your class `Main` or repl.it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter your first double: ");
double firstDouble = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("You entered " + firstDouble + " as your first number.");

System.out.print("Enter you second double: ");
double secondDouble = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("You entered " + secondDouble + " as you second number.");

System.out.print("Enter your third double: ");
double thirdDouble = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("You entered " + thirdDouble + "As your third number.");

input.close();
  }
}
```

try this code you was getting hello world because repl compiles program with name of Main.java but your program name is Input.java